Flowbite Datepicker not showing when clicked
I have an input field, which is a flowbite datepicker field.
However, when clicked, nothing happens...
Do I need to import the js file as well?
Here's what I have:
<script setup>
import Datepicker from 'flowbite-datepicker/Datepicker';

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.querySelectorAll("[datepicker]").forEach(function (datepickerEl) {
        const d = new Datepicker(datepickerEl);
        d.setOptions(datepickerOptions);

    });
});
</script>

and in the  section of the vue file:
<div class="relative max-w-sm">
    <div class="absolute inset-y-0 start-0 flex items-center ps-3 pointer-events-none">
        <svg class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true"                                             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
          <path d="M20 4a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-2V1a1 1 0 0 0-2 0v1h-3V1a1 1 0 0 0-2 0v1H6V1a1 1 0 0 0-2 0v1H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v2h20V4ZM0 18a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V8H0v10Zm5-8h10a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H5a1 1 0 0 1 0-2Z" />
         </svg>
      </div>
      <input datepicker datepicker-autohide type="text" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full ps-10 p-2.5  dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Select date" id="datepickerEL">
</div>

So input field is shown correctly. But as said, nothing happens. I probably miss a portion of code here...

document.querySelectorAll("[datepicker]") seems a little strange, usually there is a tag, id or class there

it selects all <input datepicker .....> elements

Ok, is datepickerOptions a valid object like {
format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
startDate: '2024-04-09',
endDate: '2024-04-30',
} ? In the code provided, the variable seems like it is not defined.

Not yet a solution, however, I'm one step further.
The problem seems to be the modal....
When I'm using the datepicker in a 'normal' vue view, it works. However, when having the same code in a modal, the drop-down does not work.

Have you checked in your DOM if the drop-down exists/is actually there when you click your date-picker? My guess is that your dropdown does work but you don't see it on the page because is it behind the modal, or its position is alterned because of the modal's position. That means you have a css problem. Just a guess!!
